# Extract the date and values to create a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-extraction

Here are three sample data files (text files) from my folder. I tried to extract the date corresponding to each data file and create a data frame for all the three files.
Following are the files:

File1:

```
### DEFAULTS ###
### OPTIONS ###
Title 2 left      $ Date and time: 2010-02-03 12:00 UTC
###  DATA  ### 
250 23.54300 0.00000 12.90000
500 17.47400 3.50000 21.70000
750 41.33200 22.10000 30.40000
```

File2:

```
### DEFAULTS ###
### OPTIONS ###
Title 2 left      $ Date and time: 2010-02-10 12:00 UTC 
###  DATA  ###
250 36.95300 30.60000 27.10000
500 40.87700 37.80000 27.80000
750 41.46100 38.30000 30.70000
```

File3:

```
### DEFAULTS ###
### OPTIONS ###
Title 2 left      $ Date and time: 2010-02-17 12:00 UTC 
###  DATA  ###
250 28.91200 24.90000 5.00000
500 49.82900 32.40000 11.10000
750 50.83600 40.60000 22.20000
```

Below is the code I wrote for the extracting the date.

```
### Start R Code for extracting date
setwd("C:/Users/")
path = "~C:/Users"
file.names<- dir("C:/Users/", pattern =".dat")
file.names

fileNameVector <- NULL
dateNameVector <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){

  x<-readLines(file.names[i])
  x
  date.list<-x[3]
  date.list

  xx<-strsplit(date.list,' ')
  xx

  date.fin<-unlist(xx)[13]

  fileNameVector <- rbind(fileNameVector, file.names[i])
  dateNameVector <- rbind(dateNameVector, date.fin)

}

finalDateName <- cbind(fileNameVector, dateNameVector)
finalDateName
```

and for extracting values:

```
setwd("C:/Users")
path = "~C:/Users"
st021ozone<-""
file.names<- dir("C:/Users", pattern =".dat")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- read.table(file.names[i],skip=4,header=FALSE, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  st021ozone <- rbind(st021ozone, file)
}
write.table(st021ozone, file = "st021ozone",sep=",", 
            row.names = FALSE, qmethod = "double",fileEncoding="windows-1252")
```

I want to join this two codes and make a complete data frame where the date is on the left side of the table corresponding to the 250 value in each file. The final data frame will be will have 9 rows and 5 columns.

Here is the desired result:

```
2010-02-03 250 23.54300 0.00000 12.90000
           500 17.47400 3.50000 21.70000
           750 41.33200 22.10000 30.40000
2010-02-10 250 36.95300 30.60000 27.10000
           500 40.87700 37.80000 27.80000
           750 41.46100 38.30000 30.70000
2010-02-17 250 28.91200 24.90000 5.00000
           500 49.82900 32.40000 11.10000
           750 50.83600 40.60000 22.20000
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Edit: Here is one sample of the file. I have 53 similar files:

```
$
### DEFAULTS ###
Color scale       $ 
Contour levels    $ 
Contour colors    $ 
Contour type      $ 
Map limits        $ 
Map projection    $ 
### OPTIONS ###
Image order       $ 1
Title 1 left      $ Case 0236-004 - Vertical 
Vertical 
Title 2 left      $ Date and time: 2010-09-08 
Receptor code: Town021
Title 3 left      $ 
Title 4 left      $ 
Title 1 right     $ 
Title 2 right     $ tranport
Title 3 right     $ Start: 2010-01-01 00:00 UTC
Title 4 right     $   
gar-0236-004-01-20151103085553.png
###  DATA  ###
1 1 0 1 1.83400 32.00000 0.00000 21.20000
1 1 100 1 3.27300 0.00000 25.10000 21.90000
1 1 250 1 12.22200 0.00000 34.30000 25.60000
1 1 500 1 27.27400 0.00000 35.00000 31.30000
1 1 750 1 26.45300 0.00000 36.10000 35.90000
1 1 1000 1 32.62200 0.00000 36.40000 39.30000
1 1 1500 1 35.22700 0.00000 36.70000 42.20000
1 1 2000 1 37.90300 0.00000 37.40000 43.80000
1 1 3000 1 47.28200 0.00000 44.30000 46.90000
1 1 4000 1 51.01200 0.00000 49.00000 49.90000
1 1 5000 1 61.06500 0.00000 49.40000 51.00000
```

@alistaire Thank you for the link.Here is the code that I tried to execute.

```
setwd("C:/Users/")
path = "~C:/Users/"
test.sample<-""
files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = '\\.dat'), readLines) 
test.sample<- rbind(test.sample, files)
do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(lines){
  # for each file, return a data.frame of the datetime, pulled with regex
   data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(sub('^.*Date and time: ', '', lines[grep('Date and time:', lines)])),
             # and the data, read in as text
         read.table(text = lines[(grep('DATA', lines) + 1):length(lines)]))
  }))
write.table(test.sample, file = "test.sample", sep="\t", qmethod ="double",row.names = FALSE,fileEncoding="windows-1252")
```

I assigned a file name and gave a path. When I wrote the variable name 'test.sample' in to console, I got a matrix:[see image for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClfVr.png)
I think I am missing something??? NB. Here I am using a folder with 44 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cases are mostly a matter of hacking through the mess, though some patterns make life easier. Since the files are at least regular, you don't need too much here to get something useful:

```
# read files into a list
files <- lapply(paste0('File', 1:3, '.dat'), readLines)

# loop across files (into list) with `lapply`, recombine list with `do.call(rbind, ...`
do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(lines){
    # for each file, return a data.frame of the datetime, pulled with regex
    data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(sub('^.*Date and time: ', '', lines[3])),
               # and the data, read in as text
               read.table(text = lines[5:length(lines)]))
}))

#              datetime  V1     V2   V3   V4
# 1 2010-02-03 12:00:00 250 23.543  0.0 12.9
# 2 2010-02-03 12:00:00 500 17.474  3.5 21.7
# 3 2010-02-03 12:00:00 750 41.332 22.1 30.4
# 4 2010-02-10 12:00:00 250 36.953 30.6 27.1
# 5 2010-02-10 12:00:00 500 40.877 37.8 27.8
# 6 2010-02-10 12:00:00 750 41.461 38.3 30.7
# 7 2010-02-17 12:00:00 250 28.912 24.9  5.0
# 8 2010-02-17 12:00:00 500 49.829 32.4 11.1
# 9 2010-02-17 12:00:00 750 50.836 40.6 22.2
```

Edit as you see fit.

---

#### Edit

For the new file structure, now more independent of line numbers:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(lines){
    # for each file, return a data.frame of the datetime, pulled with regex
    data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(sub('^.*Date and time: ', '', lines[grep('Date and time:', lines)])),
               # and the data, read in as text
               read.table(text = lines[(grep('DATA', lines) + 1):length(lines)]))
}))

#      datetime V1 V2   V3 V4     V5 V6   V7   V8
# 1  2010-09-08  1  1    0  1  1.834 32  0.0 21.2
# 2  2010-09-08  1  1  100  1  3.273  0 25.1 21.9
# 3  2010-09-08  1  1  250  1 12.222  0 34.3 25.6
# 4  2010-09-08  1  1  500  1 27.274  0 35.0 31.3
# 5  2010-09-08  1  1  750  1 26.453  0 36.1 35.9
# 6  2010-09-08  1  1 1000  1 32.622  0 36.4 39.3
# 7  2010-09-08  1  1 1500  1 35.227  0 36.7 42.2
# 8  2010-09-08  1  1 2000  1 37.903  0 37.4 43.8
# 9  2010-09-08  1  1 3000  1 47.282  0 44.3 46.9
# 10 2010-09-08  1  1 4000  1 51.012  0 49.0 49.9
# 11 2010-09-08  1  1 5000  1 61.065  0 49.4 51.0
```

Comment: Thank you @alistaire. This is a coincise solution. I am really having trouble with my actual data. My folder has 48 files and the file name starts something like " xxx456-45-2010453.dat".  The date in line 13 and the data values has 18 lines ( unlike 3 lines in the question),which starts at line 44. There is data set jargon between line 1 and 13 and line 13 and line 44. I tried scan,paste to get the files but I don't know where I am missing something.

Comment: How far did you get? You can make a list of files with `list.files`, which can take a `pattern` argument if there are other files in the folder, e.g. `list.files(pattern = '\\.dat')`. As far as parsing, changing the indices will do it if they're organized consistently. If not, you can pick out the lines you need by subsetting with `grep`.

Comment: I have added one sample file to the above question. Can you please tweak your code with respect to the file updated above.

Comment: With the above edit you are able to get the data frame of one files. It is still bugging me how to include all the 48 files in the folder and create a data frame as one data set which you did in your first answer. Can you please include the number of files (i.e. 48) in the code. Thanks.

Comment: That part hasn't changed; adjust the code from the original to match the files you have; integrating what I told you in my last comment, `files <- lapply(list.files(pattern = '\\.dat'), readLines)`

Comment: Thank you @alistaire. That worked. Finally I want to assign a name to the new data set so that it can be easy to manipulate. I used: 'write.table(test.sample, file = "test.sample",sep=",", row.names = FALSE, qmethod = "double",fileEncoding="windows-1252")' but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "Assign" means save to a variable (like I assume you did with `test.sample`); "write" means save to a file. Since you're using `sep = ","` and `qmethod = "double"`, you might as well use `write.csv`, where they're defaults. Other than that, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the line. Is it giving you an error? If not, have you checked your working directory?

Comment: @alistaire.I used the write.csv as the last line of the code instead of write.table, this time it executed but didn't form a meaningful file. My aim is to save it to file. I used the same pattern as the code I wrote above for extraction of values from the files. I set the path and the file name but it doesn't seem to write it in to single file.

Comment: Is what you assigned to your variable what you want to save? Have you tried dropping parameters to see if one is causing a problem? You need to troubleshoot; I can't really do it for you.

Comment: Yes, I created a path and file name and tried to save it to that (test.sample) file name. I also tried adding and substituting some lines, but it didn't work. Since I am new  to r would you mind if you can add a line or two on how to save the new data set to a file to that code you already wrote. Thank you again for the correspondence. I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you assign it to a variable? When you type `test.sample` into the console, do you get a data.frame back? Also check out [the R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), which has links to lots of nice tutorials and resources.

Comment: Please see above the edited code. That is how I tried to do it and you will see the result I got with the link above. The tutorials looks good. Thanks again.

Comment: You haven't stored the result in `test.sample`. You need to assign the result of `do.call` to it; R does not assign for you, and certainly wouldn't know where to put it. Chop out the two lines defining `test.sample`, and put in `test.sample <- do.call(rbind, lapply(.....`. And do those tutorials.

Comment: .Thank you very much. You are AWESOME! I will go through those resources.